# "Quit" VS "Give up"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, difference, verbs, phrasal-verbs

As you are aware, the verbs "quit" and "give up" have quite similar meanings and are often used interchangeably in the sense of stopping **doing something**:

> I gave up / quit smoking.

But how about when it comes to **"something"** and not "doing something"? For instance I wonder if the following registers are both idiomatic English:

> 1. He **gave up alcohol** last year. 
>    2. He **quit alcohol** last year.

I think only #1 works and #2 is not natural English.

PS. the [similar thread](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/384048/what-is-the-basic-difference-between-quit-and-give-up) is not that helpful that it should be  to clear up my ambiguity in this case.

Comment: As one of the answers in the question to which you linked suggests _quit_ seems to be more common in North America than the UK.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out @mdewey. I have already read it within the mentioned thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that "He quit alcohol" is somewhat odd, and you would rather say "He quit drinking", or "gave up alcohol".

On the other hand we do say, with a different meaning "He quit his job"